$\mathrm{Tor}$'s for submodules of division rings
Let $R$ be a ring, $D$ a division $R$-ring in which $R$ embeds, and $M$ a finitely generated $R$-submodule of $D$. What, if anything, can be said about the finiteness properties of $M$? $\mathrm{Tor}^R_n(D,M)$? Is there a simple example where $\mathrm{Tor}^R_1(D,M)\neq 0$?
(I have no intuition for this sort of thing, and am primarily interested in concrete examples.)

Not necessarily. Embed a free group algebra k[F] in a division ring D and let k be the trivial k[F] module. Then, Tor_1(k,D) has dimension rank(F)-1 over D. (Of course k is not a submodule of D.)

(I cannot seem to edit the comment above, but it was in response to a now-deleted question about D over R being flat automatically.)

For an example related to group algebras, I recommend having a look at Lemma 2.8 (5) of the following nice paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.08454, which in particular applies to group algebras of free-by-cyclic groups. If I haven’t misread anything it should tell you that $Tor_1(D,M)$=0 for all R-submodules M of D in this case.

Thanks for the link. They seem to be getting a lot of mileage out of the crossed product/Ore condition which makes it feel not unlike the commutative case (which is I guess what we're used to thinking about, whence the deleted comment) one level up and the free group (where Tor_1=0) at the bottom.

Exactly, and I expect that if one looks at a less nice torsion-free group it’s group algebra will likely not have $Tor_1=0$ in all the cases you ask.
